# Network stream problem

Tags: c#, .net

I have a server with multiple threads. Here is my server connection:

```
while (true) {
    client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    sThread a = new sThread(form1, listaThreads);

    lock(Program.lockThreads) {
            listaThreads.Add(a);
    }
    Thread clientThread =
        new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(a.HandleClientComm));
    clientThread.Start(client);
}
```

In my sThread class I have the following code:

```
public void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    String a = "";

    try // nu uita sa pui inapoi!
    {
            tcpClient = (TcpClient) client;
            clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            sr = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            sw = new StreamWriter(clientStream);

            a = sr.ReadLine();
    ...
```

But in some cases I get an error at `a = sr.ReadLine();` that says the following: [image: screenshot]

What can it be?

Comment: It looks like the connection is cut before it can start reading. Step through the code and look at the state of the socket right before the exception occurs. See if you have a firewall running somewhere that might block this kind of connection.

Comment: The connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - if the message is on the client, the server called .Close() or similar, or vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes remote hosts reboot, or the user kills the client program, or routers reboot losing their state and drop all the connections that they used to carry.

Handling client disconnects is just part of programming reliable software, and you should handle this `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` by cleaning up whatever state you have stored for the client and moving on.

Of course, if you also wrote the client software and your users say *it* is giving similar error messages, then you should investigate further. :)